# Find a cubic polynomial satisfying the given conditions

Tags: polynomials

Find $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d $, where a, b, c and d are real constants, satisfying the following conditions:

$1)\quad 4x^3 - 12x^2 + 12x - 3 \le p(x) \le 2019(x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x) - 2018,$ for all values of $x \ge 1$.

$2)\quad p(2) = 2011.$

My idea: 
The condition $(1) \iff 4(x - 1)^3 + 1\le p(x) \le 2019(x - 1)^3 + 1 $ , for all $x \ge 1.$

Therefore, I predict $p(x) = a(x - 1)^3 + 1 $, where $4 \le a \le 2019 $ . But, I still don't prove this. Please everyone help me.

Comment: You also need condition (2), which rather restricts your choice of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Continue with what you obtained,

$$4(x - 1)^3 + 1\le p(x) \le 2019(x - 1)^3 + 1 $$

and rearrange,

$$4(x - 1)^3 \le p(x) - 1 \le 2019(x - 1)^3 $$

Assume $p(x) - 1 = a(x-1)^3$ and substitute $p(2) = 2011$ to obtain $a = 2010$. Thus,

$$p(x) = 2010(x-1)^3+1$$

Edit:

Assume, instead, a general form $p(x)-1=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(x-1)^k$ with $a_k\ge 0$. Note that,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} a_k(x-1)^k > 2019(x-1)^3,\>\>\> k>3$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} a_k(x-1)^k < 4(x-1)^3,\>\>\> k<3$$

which leads to $a_k = 0 $, for $k\ne 3$.

Comment: Why is p(x) - 1 = a(x-1)^3? Can you prove this?

Comment: @LouisSaha - If $n>3$, $a(x-1)^n> 2019(x-1)^3,\>x\to \infty$; if $n<3$, $a(x-1)^n< 4(x-1)^3,\>x\to \infty$.

Comment: Why not p(x) - 1 = a(x - 1)^3 + mx^2 + nx + p?

Comment: How do you get p(x) - 1 = a(x - 1)^3?

Comment: @LouisSaha - Let $p(x) -1=\sum c_n(x-1)^n$. Use the argument above to show $c_n= 0$, except for $c_3$.

Comment: Can you post your full solution?